# angular.isObject() method not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

angular provided `angular.isObject` method is not working on angular template file. I have used this function in my template as you can see below :

```
<div class="row no-padding" ng-if="angular.isString(student)">
{{student}}
</div>
```

Please help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made a simple solution for your need.

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.student = "Dharmendra";
   $scope.isThisAnObject = function(input) {
        return angular.isString(input);
   };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div class="row no-padding" ng-if="isThisAnObject(student)"> {{student}}
    </div>
</div>
```